# day of week and hour of day in a if statement c#

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement, dayofweek, timeofday

I want to do something if the day, and time of the day equal true in a if statement. I have the day part down, just can't figure out the time part out. Let say I wan the time to be 9AM.

Here is what I have so far

```
var dt_check_monday = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if (dt_check_monday == DayOfWeek.Monday && time_now = DateTime.Now.Hour==9)
{
//do something
}
```

I can't use this I get an error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.TimeSpan'

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with the timespan  `time_now`?

Comment: Note this code won't compile, `time_now` is not declared.

Comment: @Clint The compile error we see seems to indicate that `time_now` is declared _somewhere_ and has type `System.TimeSpan`. The expression is beeing interpreted like this by the compiler: `if ( ((dt_check_monday == DayOfWeek.Monday) && time_now) = (DateTime.Now.Hour == 9) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `time_now` is having `TimeSpan` datatype. So you can try this

```
if (dt_check_monday == DayOfWeek.Monday && time_now.Hours == 9)
 {
    //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

= is an assignment. == is the 'equals'

Your second = should be a ==

Answer (score 1):

You should just do this:

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && DateTime.Now.Hour == 9)
{

}
```

Your code has an assignment to an undeclared variable `time_now` and you're doing an assignment `time_now =` which is what's causing it to fail.

You should also consider revising how you name your variables, `dt_check_monday` means absolutely nothing if the value inside it is `DayOfWeek.Wednesday`, consider changing it to something like `dt_currentDayOfWeek` but that already exists in the form of `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` which is why I dropped the variable from my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep time_now for later use, you have to encase the assignment in the if-statement with paratheses.

```
var dt_check_monday = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
if (dt_check_monday == DayOfWeek.Monday && (time_now = DateTime.Now.Hour) == 9)
{
    //do something
}
```